# How to store many small integers into a byte array?

Tags: java, algorithm, compression

Im making a online game, and as in many online games i will need loads of data being transfered via internet, so i need to be able to compress data efficiently.

For instance i want to send from my client to the server my character coordinates.

Edit: yeah bad example, let me change the values...

X coordinate(say -32 to 32).(65 diferent possible values)
Y coordinate(-32 to 32).(65 diferent possible values)
Z coordinate(-16 to 16).(33 diferent possible values)

i know that X was stored before Y that was stored before Z on the byte array before sending.

i know in the server that X cannot be lower than -31 nor higher than 32, the same for the other values.

65*65*33 = 139.425 diferent possible combinations of values for the 3 numbers = 17 bits.

7 + 7 + 5 = 19 bits.

so if i were to store X in the first 7 bits, then Y in the next 7 bits and then Z in the next 5 bits it would take 19 bits and i would be able to read them back in the other side with ease, but since all the posible combinations of values those 3 numbers can take would only take 17 bits to store i feel like im losing space here.
Is there a good way to compress those 3 numbers using less than 19 bits?

of course 19 bits and 17 bits both need 3 bytes, but if it were 17 bits and 15 bits it would make a huge diference.

Comment: Is the byte array 8-bits per element or 7-bits (ASCII) ?

Comment: Where'd you get 19 from? You only need 17.

Comment: 1: Java, 2: 8-bits per element, 3:64 needs 7 bits to be stored because in 0-64 there are 65 diferent values, same for 32 that have 33 diferent values and then need 5 bits, 7+7 = 14 + 5 = 19 if i were to not use any compressing algorithm.

Comment: @rwong: **Bytes are not characters.**  There's no such thing as an ASCII byte.

Comment: @Guedez: If you're storing "64 possible values" or "32 possible values", as you said, then the values would be 0-63 or 0-31, respectively.  Hence, 6 or 5 bits.

Comment: @cHao: my mistake, edited the question for it to make more sense. now it's -32 to 32(65 possible values, 7 bits).

Comment: This whole thing smells like premature optimization to me.  Unless you're updating thousands of times a second, which is highly unlikely, it's not going to make much difference.  And it'll take extra CPU time on both client and server, so it seems like something you ought to be damn sure you need before you choose to add more load to the server to handle it.

Comment: I don't know for sure how much extra CPU will be needed to compress the data im sending thru the internet, but im sure that i will need to send a lot of data in many diferent types of messages, on some it will make a lot of diference(15 numbers ranging from 0-2 for instance, tough this especific case will probably not happen) and on others it will make no diference at all, so i will (after finishing the algorithm) use it in a case by case scenario.

Comment: For the 15 numbers from 0-2, you'd do better to make them 0-3, even if it does waste some space.  Powers of 2 are a *lot* easier for computers to work with, and if you stick to them you'll find a decent balance between bandwidth and server-side performance.

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you are after is a coding algorithm, not a compression algorithm. To compress those numbers you should know some extra information about these numbers.

For a coding algorithm: You have 65*65*33=139.425 different possible values.
Log2(139.425) ~ 17.09 therefore you would need at least 18 bits to code any of these possible values.
A simple coding scheme would be just like you said:

```
Value = Z*65*65 + Y*65 + X
```

Then to decode it:

```
X = Value % 65
Y = (Value/65) % 65
Z = (Value/65/65) % 33
```

Now Value is an integer. If you want to store it in a byte array you could split that integer into 3 bytes:

```
Byte1 = Value & 255;
Byte2 = (Value>>8) & 255;
Byte3 = (Value>>16) & 255;
```

Answer (score 2):

Many languages support bit-packing, but I don't see the advantage here. Each value is smaller than a byte, and the same number of bytes would be required whether or not they were packed, so you may as well save the small amount of time it would take to pack/unpack the values and just handle them unpacked.

Comment: As long as i could find in Java, the best i could use would be ByteBuffer, what i can use to store 1 byte, short, integer, etc.. Those are not compressed, so if i were to store a 32 inside a byte it would use the whole 8 bits instead of 5.

Comment: It's a *buffer*.  There's considerably more than one byte/int/whatever in there, or there'd be no sense in having a buffer at all.  Just get your x byte, then your y byte, then your z.

Comment: And as for those 3 wasted bits...consider this.  You need 6+6+5 (17) bits to store all 3 numbers.  You can't send 17 bits without a lot of work -- you'd have to send 24 bits (3 bytes) anyway.

Comment: ok, say i have to store 15 numbers, they all range from 0 to 2. I could use the buffer to store then in 15 bytes, or i could store each in 2 bits using only 4 bytes(what i know how to do), or even more, i could(using the "i don't know how and im asking if it's possible to do algorithm") use only 23 bits(14.348.907 diferent combinations) that is 3 bytes.

Comment: That's just multiplication and divmod.

Comment: And for smaller numbers, it makes sense to do that.  For your 5- and 6-bit numbers, though, it's a waste of effort unless you can shave off a bit somewhere and fit the whole thing in 16 bits.

Answer (score 1):

Variable integer compression is used in Google's Protocol Buffers. It is called `varint`, and is pretty simple.

http://code.google.com/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/encoding.html#varints

Comment: as long as i understood it only helps when i don't know the lengh of the message im sending or something, i don't see how it helps to store say 4 small numbers(smaller than a byte) in two bytes.

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [gelasia-compacter](https://github.com/Autopawn/gelasia-compacter).

It's a utility that packs a serie of numbers on a byte array in a way that the smaller numbers use less space (and the numbers can be as large as a long long, so you don't have to care of the special cases with very big numbers), it also has a way to unpack them that's intended to be used with a byte stream (I mean, that the data can come in many parts).

It's very good when working with a lot of small numbers, and can represent very large ones, but you can loose efficiency if the numbers are too near of the intended int type's size.

Answer (score 0):

I found this [variant](http://github.com/lemire/javaewah) of BitSet that uses compression, you should take a look at it. The author claims that the algorithm is optimized for query speed, not for space, but that it is always more space efficient than Java's BitSet class. I think that if you are sending a high volume of coords over the wire you might see the improvement compared to just serializing the bits to a BitSet and then convert to a byte[].